# IN SignalR how to open 2 clients on the same PC, same project on different ports of asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, port

I'm trying to create a simple chat using SignalR, but to test the functionality I need to open 2 clients on the same PC.  Since the application works on one port, when a new one is opened, the previous one is closed.

Comment: To test SignalR chat on the same PC, you can open multiple instances of the chat application in different browsers or in private/incognito mode. Each instance will have a different session and will be able to run independently. Additionally, you can run multiple instances of the chat application on different ports by configuring the SignalR server to listen on multiple ports. To do this, you can specify different ports in the URL when starting the SignalR connection.

Comment: how to set up these ports because I can't find proper information about it.  I can't open it in different browsers because it says that one of the files is already in use by another application

Comment: To set up multiple ports for SignalR, you need to modify your SignalR server code.
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat1");
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat2");
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat3");
    // Add more endpoints as needed
});
In the client-side code, specify the endpoint for each instance of the chat application

Comment: I still can't figure out how this will change the ports

Comment: i am so sorry for not being able to give you a clear idea but please refer here https://medium.com/linkit-intecs/how-to-create-a-chat-app-with-asp-net-core-3-1-signalr-and-angular-10-a7fde1e70933

Comment: Thank you, I just want to clarify that I have a client and a hub in one application, which is why there was a problem with launching several clients.

Comment: What is your client here? Desktop Application ? Web App?

Comment: What is the application in below sentence ?
Since the application works on one port, when a new one is opened, the previous one is closed.